# What is aligned memory allocation?

Tags: malloc, memory-alignment

I also want to know whether glibc malloc() does this.

Comment: wouldn't that be target architecture dependent? It almost certainly is aligned...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) requirements specify what address offsets can be assigned to what types.  This is completely implementation-dependent, but is generally based on word size.  For instance, some 32-bit architectures require all `int` variables start on a multiple of four.  On some architectures, alignment requirements are absolute.  On others (e.g. x86) flouting them only comes with a performance penalty.

`malloc` is required to return an address suitable for any alignment requirement.  In other words, the returned address can be assigned to a pointer of any type.  From C99 §7.20.3 (Memory management functions):

> The pointer returned if the allocation
>   succeeds is suitably aligned so that
>   it may be assigned to a pointer to any
>   type of object and then used to access
>   such an object or an array of such
>   objects in the space allocated (until
>   the space is explicitly deallocated).

Comment: the link you provide is not good. could you provide another one ? That one has multiple issues! Ty

Answer (score 87):

Suppose that you have the structure.

```
struct S {
    short a;
    int b;
    char c, d;
};
```

Without alignment, it would be laid out in memory like this (assuming a 32-bit architecture):

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
|a|a|b|b|b|b|c|d|  bytes
|       |       |  words
```

The problem is that on some CPU architectures, the instruction to load a 4-byte integer from memory only works on word boundaries.  So your program would have to fetch each half of `b` with separate instructions.

But if the memory was laid out as:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B
|a|a| | |b|b|b|b|c|d| | |
|       |       |       |
```

Then access to `b` becomes straightforward.  (The disadvantage is that more memory is required, because of the padding bytes.)

Different data types have different alignment requirements.  It's common for `char` to be 1-byte aligned, `short` to be 2-byte aligned, and 4-byte types (`int`, `float`, and pointers on 32-bit systems) to be 4-byte aligned.

`malloc` is required by the C standard to return a pointer that's properly aligned for any data type.

glibc `malloc` on x86-64 returns 16-byte-aligned pointers.

Comment: sorry, I don't undertand what do you mean by "it's common for char to be 1-byte aligned, short to be 2-byte aligned, and 4-byte types".

Comment: @Anni_housie it just means, most systems commonly use 1byte of memory to store a char, 2bytes to store short, 4bytes for int/float/pointer and so on

Comment: Or you could just re-order elements in your struct to have the int first then the short  then the two chars.. that way its going to be easy for the system to read them.

Comment: Indeed, the order the members of a struct are listed in affects the final size of the struct because of the alignment of the members.

Comment: @dan04 thanks for the answer, now I can get why 2 bytes padding are inserted between a and b. I read somewhere saying in your example there will also be another 2 bytes padding inserted in the end after member c to align the entire structure, why is this needed?

Comment: @torez233 i think it's because in the example of above with 32 bit architecture, the final 2 padding bytes will help align the next allocated instance of this structure correctly. Otherwise next allocation would have its "a" bytes occupying the final 2 bytes of the first instance's memory, next to its "c|d" bytes. on a 32 bit architecture, each memory address is 32 bits, so there were always be 32 bits loaded even if you just want the "c" char for example

Comment: @NateWilson: Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have particular memory alignemnt needs (for particular hardware or libraries), you can check out non-portable memory allocators such as [`_aligned_malloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [`memalign()`](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_3.html#SEC28). These can easily be abstracted behind a "portable" interface, but are unfortunately non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

The `malloc()` documentation says:

```
[...] the allocated memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable.
```

Which is true for most everything you do in C/C++. However, as pointed out by others, many special cases exist and require a specific alignment. For example, Intel processors support a 256 bit type: `__m256`, which is most certainly not taken in account by `malloc()`.

Similarly, if you want to allocate a memory buffer for data that is to be paged (similar to  addresses returned by `mmap()`, etc.) then you need a possibly very large alignment which would waste a lot of memory if `malloc()` was to return buffers always aligned to such boundaries.

Under Linux or other Unix systems, I suggest you use the `posix_memalign()` function:

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

This is the most current function that one wants to use for such needs.

---

As a side note, you could still use `malloc()`, only in that case you need to allocate `size + alignment - 1` bytes and do your own alignment on the returned pointer: `(ptr + alignment - 1) & -alignment` (not tested, all casts missing). Also the aligned pointer is not the one you'll use to call `free()`. In other words, you have to store the pointer that `malloc()` returned to be able to call `free()` properly. As mentioned above, this means you lose up to `alignment - 1` byte per such `malloc()`. In contrast, the `posix_memalign()` function should not lose more than `sizeof(void*) * 4 - 1` bytes, although since your size is likely a multiple of alignment, you would only lose `sizeof(void*) * 2`... unless you only allocate such buffers, then you lose a full `alignment` bytes each time.