# Unexpected memory allocation in stack segment

Tags: c, stack-memory

I am trying to see that for a given function, memory allocation on stack segment of memory will happen in contiguous way. So, I wrote below code and I got below output.

For `int` allocation I see the memory address are coming as expected but not for character array. After memory address `0xbff1599c` I was expecting next address to be `0xbff159a0` and not `0xbff159a3`. Also, since `char` is 1 byte and I am using 4 bytes, so after `0xbff159a3` I was expecting `0xbff159a7` and not `0xbff159a8`

All memory locations comes as expected if I remove char part but I am not able to get expected memory locations with character array.

My base assumption is that on stack segment, memory will always be contiguous. I hope that is not wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    printf("Value of x is %d\n", x);
    printf("Address of x is %p\n", &x);
    printf("Dereferencing address of x gives %d\n", *(&x));
    printf("\n");

    int y = 20;
    printf("Value of y is %d\n", y);
    printf("Address of y is %p\n", &y);
    printf("Dereferencing address of y gives %d\n", *(&y));
    printf("\n");

    char str[] = "abcd";
    printf("Value of str is %s\n", str);
    printf("Address of str is %p\n", &str);
    printf("Dereferencing address of str gives %s\n", *(&str));
    printf("\n");

    int z = 30;
    printf("Value of z is %d\n", z);
    printf("Address of z is %p\n", &z);
    printf("Dereferencing address of z gives %d\n", *(&z));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Value of x is 10
Address of x is 0xbff159ac
Dereferencing address of x gives 10

Value of y is 20
Address of y is 0xbff159a8
Dereferencing address of y gives 20

Value of str is abcd
Address of str is 0xbff159a3
Dereferencing address of str gives abcd

Value of z is 30
Address of z is 0xbff1599c
Dereferencing address of z gives 30
```

Comment: Please show us the code you generated the output with as that output couldn't have been generated by the code in your question.

Comment: @KerrekSB My bad buddy, thanks for pointing it out. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers from @ameyCU and @Umamahesh were good but none was self-sufficient so I am writing my answer and adding more information so that folks visiting further can get maximum knowledge.

I got that result because of concept called as **[Data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)**. As per this, computer will always try to allocate memory (*whether in heap segment or stack segment or data segment, in my case it was stack segment*) in chunks in such a way that it can read and write quickly.

**When a modern computer reads from or writes to a memory address, it will do this in word sized chunks (e.g. 4 byte chunks on a 32-bit system) or larger. Data alignment means putting the data at a memory address equal to some multiple of the word size, which increases the system's performance due to the way the CPU handles memory.**

On a 32 bits architecture, computers word size is 4 bytes, so computer will always try to allocate memory with addresses falling in multiple of 4, so that it can quickly read and write in block of 4 bytes. When there are lesser number of bytes then computer does padding of some empty bytes either in start or end.

In my case, suppose I use `char str[] = "abc";` then including EOL character `'\0'` I have requirement of 4 bytes, so there will be no padding. But when I do `char str[] = "abcd";` then including EOL character `'\0'` I have requirement of 5 bytes, now computer wants to allocate in block of 4 so it will add padding of 3 bytes (*either in start or end*) and hence complete char array will be spanned over 8 bytes in memory.

Since `int`, `long` memory requirement is already in multiple of 4 so there is no issue and **it gets tricky with `char` or `short` which are not in multiple of 4**. This explains the thing which I reported - "*All memory locations comes as expected if I remove char part but I am not able to get expected memory locations with character array.*"

**Rule of thumb** is that if your memory requirement is not in multiple of 4 (for example, 1 `short`, `char` array of size 2) then extra padding will be added and then memory allocation will happen, so that computer can read and write quickly.

---

Below is nice excerpt from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994035/what-is-aligned-memory-allocation) which explains data structure alignment.

Suppose that you have the structure.

```
struct S {
    short a;
    int b;
    char c, d;
};
```

Without alignment, it would be laid out in memory like this (assuming a 32-bit architecture):

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
|a|a|b|b|b|b|c|d|  bytes
|       |       |  words
```

The problem is that on some CPU architectures, the instruction to load a 4-byte integer from memory only works on word boundaries. So your program would have to fetch each half of b with separate instructions.

But if the memory was laid out as:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B
|a|a| | |b|b|b|b|c|d| | |
|       |       |       |
```

Then access to b becomes straightforward. (The disadvantage is that more memory is required, because of the padding bytes.)

Answer (score 2):

> Also, since char is 1 byte and I am using 4 bytes, so after 0xbff159a3 I was expecting 0xbff159a7 and not 0xbff159a8

`char` takes up `1` byte , but `str` is string and you did not count `'\0'` which is at the end of string and thus ,`char str[]="abcd"` takes up `5` bytes.

Comment: Makes sense but still it doesn't explain - "* I was expecting next address to be 0xbff159a0 and not 0xbff159a3*"

Comment: @hagrawal There is no guarantee whatsoever how the stack frame is laid out. It seems like your compiler chose to add the required three bytes of padding before `str`, not after.

Comment: Oh, ok. So does it mean memory allocation on stack is not contiguous? Why padding is required at all, before or after?

Comment: @hagrawal Same types may be contagiously allocated  because of alignment requirements. And access objects which are not improperly aligned can cause error (_may be platform dependent_), therefore it is required.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be because the addresses are aligned to boundaries(e.g. 8 byte boundary)?.

The allocations are always aligned to boundaries and allocated in chunks
in some OS. You can check using a structure. For example,
    struct A
    {
      char a;
      char b;
      int c;
    };

The size of the struct will not be 6 bytes on a UNIX/LINUX platform.

But it might vary from OS to OS.

Similar thing apply to other data types also .
Moreover, a string just points to an address allocated in a
heap if malloc is used and the allocation logic might vary
from OS to OS. The following is output from Linux box
for the same program.

Value of x is 10
Address of x is 0x7ffffa43a50c
Dereferencing address of x gives 10

Value of y is 20
Address of y is 0x7ffffa43a508
Dereferencing address of y gives 20

Value of str is abcd
Address of str is 0x7ffffa43a500
Dereferencing address of str gives abcd

Value of z is 30
Address of z is 0x7ffffa43a4fc
Dereferencing address of z gives 30

Comment: No buddy, doesn't make sense. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: The allocations always align to boundaries.  You can check using a structure. For example,

Comment: Thanks buddy, you pointed me to right direction. However your answer was not comprehensive and self-sufficient so I wrote my answer.