# Additional questions on memory alignment

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

There have previously been some great answers on memory alignment, but I feel don't completely answer some questions.

E.g.:

[What is data alignment? Why and when should I be worried when typecasting pointers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875369/what-is-data-alignment-why-and-when-should-i-be-worried-when-typecasting-pointe)

[What is aligned memory allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994035/what-is-aligned-memory-allocation)

I have an example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int32_t cast_1(int offset) {
  std::vector<char> x = {1,2,3,4,5};
  return reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(x.data()+offset)[0];
}

int32_t cast_2(int offset) {
  std::vector<char> x = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int32_t y;
  std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&y), x.data() + offset, 4);
  return y;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << cast_1(1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << cast_2(1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The `cast_1` function outputs a ubsan alignment error (as expected) but `cast_2` does not.  However, `cast_2` looks much less readable to me (requires 3 lines).  `cast_1` looks perfectly clear on the intent, even though it is UB.

Questions:

1) Why is `cast_1` UB, when the intent is perfectly clear?  I understand that there may be performance issues with alignment.

2) Is `cast_2` a correct approach to fixing the UB of `cast_1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Why is `cast_1` UB?

Because the language rules say so. Multiple rules in fact.

1. The offset where you access the object does not meet the alignment requirements of `int32_t` (except on systems where the alignment requirement is 1). No objects can be created without conforming to the alignment requirement of the type.
2. A `char` pointer may not be aliased by a `int32_t` pointer.

> 2) Is `cast_2` a correct approach to fixing the UB of `cast_1`?

`cast_2` has well defined behaviour. The `reinterpret_cast` in that function is redundant, and it is bad to use magic constants (use `sizeof`).

Comment: For `cast_2`, is `std::memcpy(&y, x.data() + offset, sizeof(y));` better?  For the 1st question, is there really no better answer than "the rules say so"?

Comment: Well, the reason that anything is UB is just that the standard says so. That's the definition. I described the motivation in my answer. And yes, that code looks good.

Comment: @thc It's unclear to me what you mean by "better answer". Yes, using `sizeof` would be better, and would guarantee correctness on systems where the size is not 4. As an alternative to second operand, you could use `&x[offset]`, but that's up to your own preference.

Comment: Thanks for both your comments!

Answer (score 1):

WRT the first question, it would be trivial for the compiler to handle that for you, true. All it would have to do is *pessimize every other non-char load in the program*.

The alignment rules were written precisely so the compiler can generate code that performs well on the many platforms where aligned memory access is a fast native op, and misaligned access is the equivalent of your memcpy. Except where it could prove alignment, the compiler would have to handle *every* load the slow & safe way.