# Why am I receiving an "Access Violation" Error on this memcpy function?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, memcpy, shellcode

When running this program in Visual Studio, I receive an "Access Violation" error when the program reaches the memcpy function. No matter what size I make this buffer, it always throws this read access violation error. I've set breakpoints at the memcpy function and as soon as I continue the execution, it throws this error:

[snip of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6moq.png)

```
char data[DATA_SIZE] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
```

```
#define DATA_SIZE 27136

void spawn(void * buffer, int length, char * key);

typedef struct {
    int  offset;
    int  length;
    char key[4];
    int  gmh_offset;
    int  gpa_offset;
    char payload[DATA_SIZE];
} phear;

extern char data[DATA_SIZE];
```

```
void start(HINSTANCE mhandle) {
    
    phear * payload = (phear *)data;
    char * buffer;

    buffer = (char *)malloc(payload->length);
    memcpy(buffer, payload->payload, payload->length);

    /* execute our code */
    spawn(buffer, payload->length, payload->key);

    /* clean up after ourselves */
    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Which pointer is it accessing when it faults? The source or the destination? What is the value of `payload->length`? Is it greater than `DATA_SIZE` for example? Is `data` somehow invalid? That is, there is alot more debugging data needed.

Comment: `(phear *)data;` why would there be `phear` at `data`? At least, `data` is not _aligned_ to `phear`.

Comment: `data` is not a `phear`, nor can you treat it as such.  Aside from the alignment problem, it's clearly smaller than an actual `phear`.  Stop messing around with type casts.  They aren't needed for this, and they're allowing bugs.  If you need a `phear`, then *declare* a `phear`, not a `char` array.

Comment: Expanding on Tom's comment, do: `phear data;` and `extern phear data;` and eliminate the casts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several problems here:

- `data` might not be correctly aligned for `phear`. See [What is aligned memory allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994035/what-is-aligned-memory-allocation)
- `payload->length` is a strict aliasing violation: this is defined as `(*payload).length` and the expression `*payload` accesses memory through an expression of type `phear` but there is no object of type `phear` at that location.
- (If we ignore the above two problems for a moment) The `memcpy` reads out of bounds because `sizeof data < sizeof(phear)`.

A simple solution would be to use `extern phear data;` instead of the char array. If you really want to use the char array then copy data in and out of it with `memcpy` instead of struct access.